# SQL Arithmetics on rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to find the difference between row 2 and row 1(2-1) for each column,I'm lost on how to approach this, I might be doing this wrong from the beginning for all I know. 
The 2 sub queries return the rows I'm interested in and the rest is me trying to put them together in a table to operate operate on them, but needing direction ATM

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY totalhopper_01 ASC) AS rownum,TotalHopper_01,TotalHopper_02,TotalHopper_03,TotalHopper_05,TotalHopper_06 FROM 
(

SELECT * FROM(
SELECT TOP 1 TotalHopper_01,TotalHopper_02,TotalHopper_03,TotalHopper_05,TotalHopper_06 FROM mm_Cycle_Data
 WHERE TotalHopper_01 IS NOT NULL
 AND TotalHopper_02 IS NOT NULL  
 AND TotalHopper_03 IS NOT NULL 
 AND TotalHopper_05 IS NOT NULL 
 AND TotalHopper_06 IS NOT NULL 
 AND  get_address=38 AND t_stamp> '2015-10-28 07:00:00' ORDER BY t_stamp ASC)a

 UNION

 SELECT * FROM (
SELECT TOP 1 TotalHopper_01,TotalHopper_02,TotalHopper_03,TotalHopper_05,TotalHopper_06 FROM mm_Cycle_Data
 WHERE 
 TotalHopper_01 IS NOT NULL
 AND TotalHopper_02 IS NOT NULL  
 AND TotalHopper_03 IS NOT NULL 
 AND TotalHopper_05 IS NOT NULL 
 AND TotalHopper_06 IS NOT NULL 
 AND get_address=38 AND t_stamp> '2015-11-17 07:00:00' ORDER BY t_stamp ASC)b
 )c
```

Results

```
rownum               TotalHopper_01 TotalHopper_02 TotalHopper_03 TotalHopper_05 TotalHopper_06
-------------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- --------------
1                    182450272      8343796        2539352        0              0
2                    339742596      19222977       4940526        0              0
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps create a temp table and populate with required data first then run your query ??

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (TotalHopper_01,TotalHopper_02,TotalHopper_03,TotalHopper_05,TotalHopper_06)
select TOP 1 TotalHopper_01,TotalHopper_02,TotalHopper_03,TotalHopper_05,TotalHopper_06  
FROM mm_Cycle_Data
WHERE TotalHopper_01 IS NOT NULL
 AND TotalHopper_02 IS NOT NULL  
 AND TotalHopper_03 IS NOT NULL 
 AND TotalHopper_05 IS NOT NULL 
 AND TotalHopper_06 IS NOT NULL 
 AND  get_address=38 AND t_stamp> '2015-10-28 07:00:00' ORDER BY t_stamp ASC

INSERT INTO #TempTable   (TotalHopper_01,TotalHopper_02,TotalHopper_03,TotalHopper_05,TotalHopper_06)
select TOP 1    TotalHopper_01,TotalHopper_02,TotalHopper_03,TotalHopper_05,TotalHopper_06  
FROM mm_Cycle_Data
WHERE  TotalHopper_01 IS NOT NULL
 AND TotalHopper_02 IS NOT NULL  
 AND TotalHopper_03 IS NOT NULL 
 AND TotalHopper_05 IS NOT NULL 
 AND TotalHopper_06 IS NOT NULL 
 AND get_address=38 AND t_stamp> '2015-11-17 07:00:00' ORDER BY t_stamp ASC

-- get summary of data
SELECT SUM(TotalHopper_01) as totalHopper_01,SUM(TotalHopper_02) as totalHopper_02  
FROM #TempTable

-- clean up the temp table when finished
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```